how to use twilio voice node in thingsboard cloud
When using twilio voice rule chains node in thingsboard cloud
'com/ctc/wstx/stax/WstxInputFactory'
An error occurs.
Are there any cases of successfully using twilio voice node on thingsboard cloud?
I used twilio voice node in thingsboard rule chins.
Message transmission to the relevant node is normal, but an error occurs at the relevant node.
error: 'com/ctc/wstx/stax/WstxInputFactory'
